# custom validator for charfield do not raise any error

Tags: django, validation, model, field

I have done a validator that is supposed to check the input from a charfield:

```
def postnvali(value):
    
    if not value.isalnum():
        raise ValidationError(_('postnummer måste vara siffror'))
```

it is used in the following model:

```
class Adress(Model):

    street=CharField(max_length=100)
    snumb=CharField(max_length=15)
    town=CharField(max_length=100)
    postn=CharField(max_length=5,validators=[postnvali])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'city: ' + self.town

    class Meta:
        ordering=('street','town')
```

but when using admin and entering the wrong format, nothing happens, no error message. why?

Comment: How does the wrong format looks like? Can you explain *what* you aim to validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [**`str.isalnum(…)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) returns:

> Return True if all characters in S are **alphanumeric**.

This means that the characters can be numbers (0-9), or *alphabetical* (A-Za-z), but based on the error message, you want to only allow *digits*. You thus should use The function [**`str.isdigit(…)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

> Return True if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, False otherwise.

So we can rewrite the validator to:

```
def postnvali(value):
    
    if not value.isdigit():
        raise ValidationError(_('postnummer måste vara siffror'))
```